# Align rows in Vuetify's card component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Here's my simple example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-yhz1w?fontsize=14

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-content class="ma-4">
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <v-card height="200" width="400" style="border: 1px; border-color: black;">
            <v-content class="ma-2">
              <v-row>
                <v-col>Top Left</v-col>
                <v-col>Top Right</v-col>
              </v-row>
              <v-row>
                <v-col>Bottom Left</v-col>
                <v-col>Bottom Right</v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-content>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

I have a card, and want to know, how can I align these titles, according to their meaning. Top Left must be close to the top left corner, Bottom Right - to the bottom right corner, and so on.

What shall I add to my layout to properly align it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the doc, you need to give the height for v-row. Otherwise it will remain in its minimal height.

```
<v-row style="height: 100px">
  <v-col>Top Left</v-col>
  <v-col align="right">Top Right</v-col>
</v-row>
<v-row align="end" style="height:100px">
  <v-col>Bottom Left</v-col>
  <v-col align="right">Bottom Right</v-col>
</v-row>
```

Comment: It works, but how to align bottom titles to bottom corners then?

Comment: It is aligning the bottom tiles to bottom corners.